# In separable, inner-product space X every complete orthonormal set is closed and vice versa

Tags: functional-analysis

English is not my native language so if anything needs definition just tell me. I have a problem with proving that if set is closed then it is complete

Let $\{\varphi _{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty }$ be an orthonormal set. Lets take an element $f\in X$ and lets introduce coefficients $c_{k}=(f\cdot \varphi _{k})$ and partial sum $S_{_{n}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}\varphi _{k}$

I learnt from Bessels inequality that $\parallel f-S_{n} \parallel ^{2}=\parallel f \parallel^{2} -\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}^{2}$

Also from Parseval equality $\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}^{2}$ converges to $\parallel f \parallel^{2}$ for n ->$\infty$

And from now on I am lost, and cant understand the rest of the proof.

$\lim_{n\to\infty }\parallel f-S_{n}\parallel ^{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty }(\parallel f \parallel^{2} -\sum_{k=1}^{n}c_{k}^{2})=0$

so this implies than $S_{n}$ converges to f

f is of our choice and $S_{n}$ are all possible linear combinations of elements of orthonormal set $\{\varphi _{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty }$

So $S_{n}$ converges to f, and the set of all $S_{n}$ is dense in space X:$\overline{\{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha _{k}\varphi _{k},\alpha \in\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$=X and this implies orthonormal set $\{\varphi _{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty }$ is complete

Comment: Can you state more precisely what you are trying to prove?  In particular, what does "closed" mean in this context?  Any orthonormal set is closed in the usual sense of the term "closed set"...

Comment: The proof is complete I just dont understand it and closed means that Parseval equality is valid that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }c_{k}^{2}=\parallel f\parallel ^{2}$ where $c_{k}=(f\cdot \varphi _{k})$.
I just dont understand why are we creating the linear combinations and the end of the proof